# SQL Server Datediff returning overflow error when query has no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

The query returns no results even on the ones where it does work and I am getting the following error.

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of
>   dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use
>   datediff with a less precise datepart.

But there is nothing to overflow

The following work:

```
SELECT cis.SaleBK   
FROM dbo.Sales cis
INNER JOIN dim.CalendarDate sd on cis.SaleDateFK = sd.CalendarDatePK
WHERE sd.CalendarDate >= DATEADD(day,-1,dbo.DateToday())
```

And this one:

```
SELECT cis.SaleBK
       ,DATEDIFF(s,'1969-01-01',sd.CalendarDate) as SortOrder
FROM dbo.Sales cis
INNER JOIN dim.CalendarDate sd on cis.SaleDateFK = sd.CalendarDatePK
WHERE sd.CalendarDate = DATEADD(day,-1,dbo.DateToday())
```

But this does not and I can't figure out why

```
SELECT cis.SaleBK
       ,DATEDIFF(s,'1969-01-01',sd.CalendarDate) as SortOrder
FROM dbo.Sales cis
INNER JOIN dim.CalendarDate sd on cis.SaleDateFK = sd.CalendarDatePK
WHERE sd.CalendarDate >= DATEADD(day,-1,dbo.DateToday())
```

Comment: Do you have any `CalendarDate` values more than ~24 years in the future? If so, the number of seconds since 1969 is more than `DATEDIFF` can return. Also, why `dbo.DateToday()`?

Comment: Ah it's just a small function on my db that we use instead of getdate, returns the getdate without the time. In this case it doesn't serve any real purpose however I use it out of habit.

Comment: Also, yes CalendarDate goes up to 2050 but it's keyed on the Sales table which only has sales up to yesterday so surely it shouldn't be doing datediff on anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a loop to check when `datediff` returns an error:

```
; with  Dates as
        (
        select  cast('2012-01-01' as date) as dt
        union all
        select  dateadd(day, 1, dt)
        from    Dates
        )
select  dt
,       DATEDIFF(s,'1969-01-01',dt)
from    Dates
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

The number of seconds since `1969-01-01` and `2037-01-20` is the first that is too large.

So it looks like the maximum number returned by `DateDiff` is `2^31` or `2147483647`.

You can avoid the error by limiting the query's date range, like:

```
WHERE  sd.CalendarDate >= DATEADD(day,-1,dbo.DateToday())
       and sd.CalendarDate < '2037-01-20'
```

Comment: Wow that works, however I don't understand why it was trying to do the datediff when the query returns no results.

Comment: SQL Server might evaluate the `select` BEFORE applying the `where` clause.  I've had that happen with division-by-zero errors too, not sure exactly when this behavior is allowed.

Comment: But surely it couldn't evaluate anything in the CalendarDate table which isn't linked to the Sales table? As there are no Sales after yesterday so it should never even see those values in CalendarDate?

Comment: It might retrieve all the rows from CalendarDate, calculate the datediff, then run the `where` clause, and only later join them to Sales.